# Add Color Palette to MapView-Map

Tags: r, r-sf, color-palette, r-mapview

I'm trying to change the colours of a map (shapefile data), created by a code similar to this:

```
mapView(MyData, zcol="Column_Name")
```

The "Help" page gives two different ways to change colour by using `color=` or `col.regions=`.
I would like to add a specific palette (`YlGn`), but haven't found a way to do so. All it says is:

```
Error in col2rgb(colors, alpha = alpha) : invalid color name 'YlGn'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example that should clarify the point.

```
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(RColorBrewer)

mapview(franconia, zcol = "SHAPE_LEN", col.regions=brewer.pal(9, "YlGn"))
```

[image]